# Lipschitz Function over the real axis

Tags: lipschitz-functions

Let the following function: 
\begin{equation}
\pi(x) = \frac{e^x}{1 + e^x},\quad \textrm{for all } x \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}
I want to know if it is Lipschitz? Here my proof and I like to know if it is true?

\begin{equation}
\pi'(x) = \frac{e^x}{(1 + e^x)^2}.
\end{equation}

Using the fact that for all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ we have $ (1 + e^x)^2 > 1+e^x > e^x,$ then I can conclude that for all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ we have $|\pi'(x)| < 1.$ 
Hence, the derivative of $\pi(\cdot)$ is bounded. Then, I conclude that the function $\pi(\cdot)$ is $k-$lipschitz for some $k\leq 1.$

Best regards,

Comment: It's correct (but not enough), you need to use the mean value theorem to conclude.

Comment: @idm I supose the OP already knows how to prove a function is Lipschitz if the derivative is bounded (MVT), otherwise hardly would he have calculated the derivative and etc. Under this assumption, I think the above is correct. +1